# How to get device hotspot SSID programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I'm struggling to find a way to find `hotspot ssid` of the device, all solutions which I found were returning Wi-Fi name to which device is connected while I want to find the hotspot name, which the device created.

`getting wifi name`

```
public static String getWifiName(Context context) {
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
            if (wifiInfo != null) {
                NetworkInfo.DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState());
                if (state == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED || state == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
                    return wifiInfo.getSSID();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Programmatically? Otherwise, shouldn't the hotspot app or feature that you are using tell you the name?

Comment: yup programmatically :)

Comment: Can you provide the resources you found that return the wifi names of the devices? I assume the same api would be able to tell you information about the device's network adapter

Comment: @cricket_007 see updated answer

Comment: @stackoverflowed   try this code... 

WifiManager mng = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

String currentSSID = mng.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();